# PHP - display the first record in a different way than other

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm supposed to pull data from a database and then display the first record in a different way than other.
I've done it this way but it seems a bit cumbersome

```
$result = $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE id = $id order by ordering");

if ($result)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}


$count = count($rows);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 1)
    {
         echo $rows[$i]['filename']. "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
         echo $rows[$i]['filename']. "<br>";
    }
}
```

var_dump($rows)

```
array
0 => 
  array
    'filename' => string '69_1.jpg' (length=17)
1 => 
  array
    'filename' => string '69_2.jpg' (length=17)
2 => 
  array
    'filename' => string '69_3.jpg' (length=17)
```

There is a better and cleaner way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Your code does something special on the **second** item, not the first.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf - Sorry but i don't understand ypur replay.

Comment: Wait, Dexter, I lost track of this thraed. I'l fix it

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @HassanAlthaf - I have to post my question in codereview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't get why are you creating an array first then looping over it for display, you can simple go this way

```
$result = $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE id = $id order by ordering");

if ($result)
{
    $first = true;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if ( $first)
        {
            // display your first row here
            $first = false;
            continue;
        }

        // display other rows here
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like what I was looking for. I knew that my code was not correct, but I did not know how to do it in another way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = true;

while (...) {  // or foreach () or whatever
    if ($first) {
        ...
        $first = false;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```